# Jmeter assertions using user-variables and regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am running a series of webservice tests using jmeter and I've run into a couple problems regarding assertions. Basically in one of my requests an error classification needs to be specified ( variable ${CLASS} ), and that request is supposed to return info on subscribers and devices that have that specified error. I want to assert that the classification that is returned with the other info is NEVER NOT what was inputed. i.e. classification="${CLASS}" . I'm pretty sure I'd like to use a RegEx along with jmeter's 'not contains' option in the assertion to make this happen, but I'm not too sure how to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pedantic point but NEVER NOT is a double negative, did you mean True or False?

Comment: Yes I am aware. It's because classification could possibly return one of the other error levels that isn't ${CLASS}, or along with ${CLASS}, as a lot of info is being returned in the request. I just want classification to always equal ${CLASS}. i.e. the info with classification="${CLASS}" is returned only.

Comment: So would it work if you could just use a variable as part of the string to match?

Comment: well, if in my response assertion I put something like ' classification="${CLASS}". and say ${CLASS} has a value of "minor". if the request returns the device and subscriber info and they have classification="minor" associated with them in the response. BUT a few devices have classification="major" with them (which isn't supposed to happen), then the assertion will still pass because classification="minor" is still in the response, won't it? I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I would suggest using multiple assertions. If you have multiple assertions the parent request will only pass if all of them pass, it will fail as soon as any one assertion returns a fail state.

Eg. You could have one that returns a pass status if it finds "minor" and then another that returns pass if it does NOT find "major". You specify that the assertion will fail if it finds the text by selecting the Pattern Matching Rules CONTAINS with the checkbox NOT selected and then simply including the text you want to not be present as a Pattern to Test.

You can also have multiple text strings in the same assertion but like this they will all use the same scope and pattern matching rules.

Comment: thanks for the answer. however, I got a negative look-ahead expression " classification=(?!"${CLASS}) " to work when it was set with the not contains response assertion. that way, if the value of classification ever changed from minor, the multiple assertions would not need to be changed.